# Writing SVG files in android other than Batik

Tags: android

Does anybody know a good library for writing SVG files in Android?

I've looked at batik and there is heavy dependence on AWT. SO i am looking for something that is easier to use on android.

Comment: Hi did you find any solution? i am looking for the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of looking around I found the best solution was just to write it out in SVG XML.

Answer (score 4):

Try: http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/

Answer (score 2):

I've created an SVG converter for Android, though it's in a very messy state at the moment and not really ready to publish publicly yet, but I do intend to make it fully open for others to use. When I started I didn't know about the svg-android project.

The SVG converter class I created initially parses the SVG file and holds an internal representation in lists of Paths, etc. Having parsed the raw file once it can then be used to write that image data to Canvas as much as you like. The reason I rolled my own SVG class is because I wanted to implement callbacks that let the code alter attributes of different parts of the image, so that I could draw an entire widget in Inskape and then manipulate parts of it. For example, in Inkscape I can draw a gauge, assign a particlar ID to the gauge pointer, and the code can manipulate the angle of the gauge pointer at runtime. You can use to to automatically split various groups (<g> elements) within the image into different Views. It handles various styling and nested transformation attributes pretty well. But lots of it needs polishing; my inefficient use of some objects sends the GC a bit insane...

If anyone thinks this might be what they need then if you send me a sample SVG image you'd want to use, I could perhaps put a sample project together for you. If there's any interest then I'll tidy it and properly host it somewhere.

Comment: sounds pretty good. I'd be interested to see it. I am writing a drawing program on android so maybe you might be able to make the widgets on your device ;)

Comment: how did this projecto go? any interesting results? i'm trying to use SVG files on Android...

Comment: @ffleandro - I put this up on Github: https://github.com/TrevorPage I haven't pushed any updates to that repository for many months though, although I've done lots of improvements to it locally. If you're finding it useful then let me know and I'll see about getting the repository updated.

Comment: Yes mate, please do that. I'm already seeing lots of cleanup to do. I couldn't use the svg-android project, i'll look into yours more, but I would like to push some improvements. Are you cool with that?

Comment: That would be awesome actually. I must admit that I haven't done much collaboration with Git yet, so this would be a good way for me to get used to dealing with push requests, etc. What I'll do if it's best is I'll try to synchronise the repository tonight before you push your updates if you like, as I suppose it could end up messy otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I won't modify anything before you push everything. Can't you push everything now? I'm only trying some experiments by now, but I would like to see the whole code before investing much time in this.

Comment: Finally got round to pushing the latest library and example. Apologies for the state of everything; it's actually something I did for a much larger project, and was one of the first parts of the project I did while I was properly Java, and the quality is very substandard compared to what I produce now. There are also some bits in there that I need to document properly, and / or are specific to the application it was originally created for. I'll continue to refactor and tidy it up. I really hope it's of use to you.